# Auto Date Change for monthly reports

Tags: sql, sqlplus

pretty new to posting here so be gentle :p

I run monthly queries for SOX compliance reporting.  My manager wants me to adjust the query so that we do not have to manually change the date range to the applicable month every time we run them.  What would be method to automate this task so I dont have to manually change the date range prior to running the query.  I have a .bat .log and spool my results to a .csv using sqlplus.  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Plz post some sample data and desired result.

Comment: I wish I could, that's why i was hesitant to even post since this is a work related question so I cant really post but heres a snippet of the date portion I am trying to change

Comment: AND SQLLOG_I.CREAT_DT between to_date ('12/31/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND (to_date ('02/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))  this is the line I am trying to automate so I dont have ot manually change the range after each month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getdate() function to return todays date, and then build from there.

```
 WHERE MONTH(thingDate) = MONTH(getdate()) 
 and YEAR(thingDate) = YEAR(getdate())
```

Comment: so this would be your preferred method to run the queries for the prior month correct? the sql file i received is quite complicated and I did not build it.  Can I just add this function in place of where my dates are inputted?

Comment: You can add some variation of this, yes. You didn't tell us exactly what your data looked like, so it's hard to say exactly what you should do. But this will lead you down the path.

Answer (score 0):

The `last_day` function is helpful for retrieving the last day of the current month.  There is no simple function for the first day, but a simple function such as this will do the trick:

```
to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

So using both of those with the `BETWEEN` operator in your `WHERE` clause will get you where you need to be.  You'll just need to possibly change the date format for your situation.

Comment: thing is with this method, usually im running the reports for the prior month. In February I need to run the reports for January etc

Comment: You can still use the same method, just use the same logic for first day and  subtract one day, e.g., `to_char(TRUNC(last_day(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), 'MM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')` and `last_day(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))`

Comment: When I try replacing my dates with what you put after BETWEEN i'm getting a ORA-01843 not a valid month error

Comment: Are you sure there's no copy-paste issue?  I've tested this and it works on my instance `SELECT * FROM per_all_people_f WHERE effective_start_date BETWEEN to_char(TRUNC(last_day(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY')), 'MM'), 'DD-MON-YYYY') and last_day(to_char(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - 1, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))`